# Complex join involving comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following tables with fields

**tbLicenceTypes**

> - LicenceTypes (P.K)
> - LicenceTypesX

**tbLicence**

> - LicenceType
> - AgentId

**tbProduct**

> - Product (P.K)
> - ProductX
> - LicenceType

**tbCompany**

> - CompanyId (P.K)
> - CompanyName

**tbCompanyProduct**

> - Company
> - Product

Now I want fetch all those Products (Product and ProductX from tbProduct) whose `LicenceType` matches with tbLicence 's `LicenceType` assigned to the agent and  which are assigned to company (in tbCompanyProduct).

Please help me !!!

Comment: have you tried anything? if not then give it a try first and share it in question then try something like this : `select p.* from tbProduct p join tbLicence l on p.LicenceType  = l.LicenceType  where l.agentID = 123`

Comment: let me check it thoroughly...

Comment: I am sorry i have given wrong requirement... i will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
select p.product, p.productx, c.companyname
from  tbProduct p
  join LicenceType l
    on p.LicenceType = l.LicenceType
  join tbCompanyProduct c
    on c.product = p.product
where l.agentid = 456
```